next.js app with node.js server and python server
I have deployed both frontend and backend as serverless via Vercel.
I am using node.js serverless functions well by writing src/app/api/api-name/route.ts code.
But I also want to use python serverless functions in the same Next.js project.
I know that I can use fastapi or flask as a backend in Next.js.
But what I am wondering is whether it is possible to use node.js and python serverless functions together in one next.js project?
In other words, I was wondering if it is possible to use node.js runtime and python runtime together in one next.js project if you have serverless deployment through vercel.

I am using next.js version 14 and I am using the app directory method.

NextJS is a node application, how would that even work?
